# multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ is well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote, p.10, proposition 4.

The authors indicate that the equivalence classes in the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ are:

\begin{equation}
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times = \{\bar{a}\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}|(a,n)=1\}
\end{equation}

Then they say that:

> It is easy to see that if any representative of $\bar{a}$ is
>   relatively prime to $n$ then all representatives are relatively prime to
>   $n$ so that the set on the right in the proposition is well defined.

I can not see why that is the case. Could someone help me ?

Comment: follows from $\gcd(a+nk,n)=\gcd(a,n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Representatives of $\bar a$ are $a+kn$, $k\in \mathbb Z$.

If we take any element $a+k_1n\in \bar a$ such that $\gcd(a+k_1n,n)=1$,

then for any other element $a+k_2n\in \bar a$, by a known property of the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties),

$\gcd(a+k_2n,n)=\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(a+k_1n,n)=1$ too.

Comment: $ba+cn=1\iff b(a+kn)+(c-bk)n-1$

Comment: I meant $ba+cn=1\iff b(a+kn)+(c−bk)n=1 $

Comment: Can I prove it by saying that since $a+kn = q_0 n + r_0 \Leftrightarrow a = (q_0 - k) n + r_0$, therefore only the factor $q$ will differ in the first step of the euclidean algorithm, and the gcd does not depend of $q$ ?

Comment: I think if you proceed with the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd of $a+kn$ and $n$, you will see it's the same as the gcd of $a$ and $n$